# Is there any way to control a big puppet environment?

Tags: virtual-machine, puppet

I'm getting a lot of trouble lately from my environment.

I got a big virtual environment (2500+ VMs Unix and windows) that all run puppet agents on them, but, every few and then some of them stop running the puppet agent from all kinds of reasons as run_lock exists, root is full, the cert in the master and in the agent doesn't the same and so on.

for the majority of the time, I tried to face the Linux machines with bash scripting and pssh. and the windows one throw Powershell, lately I find that very hard to control all the VMS that doesn't run puppet on them and find my self trying all day to make the environment rum puppet again.

I am new to the puppet world and here to see if there are solutions from anyone that might face the same problem as I do.

thanks, Rom.

Comment: If you're new to Puppet but have hundreds of agents on your hands, then I guess you must have inherited the setup.  In that case, I'd first talk to whomever you took over for, if possible.

Comment: With that said, even with an installed base of 2500, if you're spending a lot of time troubleshooting issues such as those you've described, then there is probably something broken in your environment, by which I mean the overall installation, not Puppet specifically.  I can think of a couple of ways that Puppet's configuration could contribute to such issues, but they're mostly along the lines of using it to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: So I think the best approach is to figure out why you are having these issues -- probably more than one reason, since you've described widely varied issues -- and fix those root causes.